# Signalr CPU surge issue without increase in load

Tags: c#, asp.net, signalr, signalr-hub

We have created a self hosted ASP.Net application for a real time streaming with signalr in place.  It was perfect with 500 simultanious users connected.  However, Im having some issues with below mentioned params

- CPU - Xeon processor with 2.6ghz, 16 Logical core.
- Streaming rate - Max 2kb per second each hub
- Users connected - 900 concurrent users
- Active Threads (as in resource manager) - 945
- CPU consumed - 10% - **FINE** (sudden surge to 40% occasionally, 3 times a day - **WHY**?)

Why there is sudden jump without any new users, more data.  Even if there is some reconnections, it should not be more than 20% (double) I hope.

Already tried these settings but no luck.  https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/signalr/overview/performance/signalr-performance#tuning

What could be reason for the occasional CPU surge. Is it something to do with Server cpu configuration or signalr needs some other tuning?  Any idea to find the root cause.

*Note, same stream with different communication medium like Dotnetty has no issues on same configuration.  Having issue only on signalr.*

Comment: Probably cleanup and the GC?

Comment: @Blindy will that cause such huge spike. Still there is not drop in memory after the time of spike.  Would that be the cause for the spike? Is there a way identify GC ran on that time?

Comment: Sure, profile your application. It's what you should have done from the beginning anyway, we don't even have your source code to guess at a reason.